# Drawn objects disappearing after set time. VB

Tags: vb.net, list, oop, drawing, picturebox

I have code that makes a list of 11 circle objects and draws them to a picture box in a VB windows form. They are supposed to move across it and when they reach the end, restart at the beginning.
The circles get populated correctly, and move as they are supposed to, but after two cycles once they reach the end they disappear and don't reset to the beginning. Here is the code i am currently using.

```
Public Class frmContent
Private chocolatemark As New List(Of circlemark) 

Public Sub frmContent_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        chocolatemark.Add(New circlemark(Rnd() * 630 + 1, Rnd() * 220 + 140))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub rndGen_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rndGen.Tick
    picturebox.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub picturebox_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles picturebox.Paint
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        chocolatemark(i).update()
        chocolatemark(i).draw(e)
    Next
End Sub
End Class

Public Class circlemark
Private pos As Point = New Point(0, 0)
Sub New(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double)
    pos.X = x
    pos.Y = y
End Sub

Public Sub draw(ByRef e As PaintEventArgs)
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, pos.X, pos.Y, 5, 5)
End Sub

Public Sub update()
    If pos.X < 640 Then
        pos.X += globalvalue.speed
    End If
    If pos.X > 640 Then
        pos.X = 0
    End If
End Sub
End Class


Public Class globalvalue
Public Shared speed As Integer = 5
End Class
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you debug and follow the code and see what is happening?

Comment: I would use the `Random` class over the `Rnd` function.

Comment: I ran it in debug mode when the disappearing occurs. No errors pop up.
Whats better about using Random?

Comment: You control the Range and `Rnd()` is an old legacy function and you should move away from them.

Comment: So does it continue to tick more than 2 times? 2 cycles?

Comment: No after 2 it disappears.
Also... lol... at myself. I figured it out.
When it resets to 0 and moves up by 5 and reaches 640, being a multiple of 5, and the reset only triggers if its greater than 640.

The circles disappear cause they are waiting off screen with nothing happening.

I just added a " >= " and all is well. I feel dumb :( I thought I was missing some large concept like lists being depopulated or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If pos.X < 640 Then
    pos.X += globalvalue.speed
End If
If pos.X > 640 Then
    pos.X = 0
End If
```

You created a black hole for the objects, one they can never escape from.  Once the value reaches 640, they'll get stuck forever.  Can't get higher, can't get back to 0.  It should of course be >= 640.

This problem became hard to diagnose (although the debugger can easily show you) because you used a "magic number".  640 isn't actually the size of the picture box.  So you couldn't *see* them being stuck.  Never use magic numbers.  PictureBox.ClientSize.Width is the correct value to use, minus the object size.  Don't hard-code that either, turns in a fleck of dust on a "retina" display.

Comment: Thanks for summarizing everything. I was going to go back and fix the magic numbers once everything worked how I wanted.

I have run into this issue quite a few times before. It seems to mess me up a bit.